# Replace simple while loop by recursion

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop

If I have an simple function (pseudocode) like

```
fun(a, b):
 x = a
 i = 0
 while i < b do
  x = x + a
  i ++
 return x
```

Can I replace the `while loop` in this function by a recursion?

Comment: What is `fun` supposed to do?

Comment: @Christian It should add value of `x` b times. So If b = 3 it should do: x + x + x, if b = 5 it should do: x + x + x + x + x

Comment: So, multiply a and b?

Comment: FYI, it is usually better to use iterative functions rather than recursive in non tail-call optimized languages like Python.

Comment: Note that `++` and `--` do not exist in Python. Here, `++` will produce a syntax error. If you try to use the preincrement/predecrement forms, they will mysteriously not do anything, since they will be interpreted as two applications of single-operand `+` or `-`.

Comment: @user2357112 I know, that's the reason why I add info "pseudocode" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
fun (a, b, i):
  if i >= b:
    return 1
  else:
    return a + fun(a, b, i + 1)
```

Comment: On first look it should `return 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using an extra parameter you can try:

```
def f(a, b):
    if b <= 1:
        return a
    else:
        return a + f(a, b - 1)
```

**Note:** This will only work for `b >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(x, y):
    if y != 0:
        for i in fun(x, y-1):
            yield x + i
    yield 0
```